# Most apps hang, then crash. Including core apps

Tags: ios, crash

Just yesterday my iphone 5S started playing up. Some apps would hang when they were opened.

Today it's pretty much all of them, even text message (and other built in apps) hangs. If left for a while they eventually crash.

Have restarted the phone, and also done a hard reset (home+power) and issue remains. Also tried google but not come up with much just yet.

Also, I have not done any updates or restores or anything like that recently. phone is about 12mo old. running 8.3

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried backing up the phone to a computer and restoring the original software on the phone, then restoring the phone with the backup?

Comment: Not tried that as I run linux which makes it kinda difficult... will see what I can do.

Comment: understood. Perhaps spinning up a Windows VM or finding a friend with a Mac/PC would help? Anyways, keep us posted - this will let us know if it's a software issue or a hardware issue as the root cause :)

Comment: dusted off a win8 vm, busy installing itunes etc. will report back later